# How to paint exterior wall when ladder needs to go from a roof section?

Tags: roof, painting

I need to paint the front of my house, but there is a section of wall that I cannot get to with a ladder on the ground.

This is the house from the side, I need to paint (C)

[image: profile of my house]

The problem is that if I put a ladder on the ground (A) then its slope is too 'gentle' (opposite of steep) to be safe.

I thought of a simple scaffold tower but it doesn't gain me anything because the ladder slope from the scaffold would be the same.

I either need to place the ladder from (B) or use one of those rental crane arms (prefer to not spend the $ for a small section of wall).

I've seen these, https://provisiontools.com/products/roof-boot would they work as a way to secure the bottom of the ladder?  I have a roofing harness and would secure myself to the roof anchor just to be safe...

Comment: Be careful with products like roof boot.   I have seen similar products - not this one - tear up shingles on a roof bad and costly repairs.   You might be better off hiring a painter for that section that has the right tools/ladders/expertise.   Myself I would probably stand on B and do it and mcgyver myself to something inside the house which would inevitably fail.  You probably need a picture for this to be answered right.

Comment: If an equipment rental place has an available 35 foot towable boom lift then I think it would be worth every penny to rent it and not hurt yourself. Make sure to get the full use out of it and paint ALL of the high spots first so that you struggle less with the ladder later.

Comment: What I do in that case is yeah, overlean the ladder... but then, place a large object at the foot of the ladder so it *can't* kick out.   Large object, like, my car :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answer.  To clarify the section to paint is beyond reach standing on the roof section :)  I will consider a boom lift and whether I will eventually need one anyway for other areas of the house.

Comment: How high does "C" rise above its base at the peak of "B" ?   If you can reach the whole thing while standing on "B"  then consider the sort of horizontal platforms that roofers use to stand on while applying shingles

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  If the ladder exceeds max lean angle, it's not the kickout to worry about:  it's the ladder collapsing mid-span due to excess transverse force.

Comment: IF there's room either side of the part that juts out, scaffolding would go there (two lots), and boards would span above the part B. With a rail, you'd be safe from left to right, and be able to change height quite easily.

Answer (score 5):

There are ways of setting up portable scaffold towers to handle this:
[image: cantilevered scaffold]

Setting them up is usually left to professionals though.

Comment: Not that the answer is wrong but in context of someone wanting to do something themselves (paint their house)... saying a huge scaffold that takes a professional to put together maybe not the answer for this person.

Comment: I got the sense that he wanted to paint his house himself, but not kill himself.  These scaffolds are extremely easy to set up, but if you don't know how to do all the complicated cantilevering, you are better off hiring someone to set it up and then go  do the painting.

Comment: @DMoore given your mcgyver solution in your other comment I think this answer is much better and safer - the cost of this is cheaper than the medical bills for a broken leg or neck.

Comment: Yes, renting a MEWP or building a scaffold would be cheaper than a typical funeral...

Comment: Where I live, each of those scaffold sections rents for about $5/day. I see 5 sections plus some accessories. Pretty darn cheap to gain a stable work platform, do a nice job of painting, and _not die_.